# Откуда у enum метод valueOf() с одним параметром?

Tags: java, enum

Откуда у enum метод `valueOf()` с одним параметром?

В [доках](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) класса Enum написано, что метод valueOf() имеет два параметра...

```
public class EnumValueOf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumClass enumClass = EnumClass.valueOf ("PHONE3");
        System.out.println (enumClass.getDigit ()); // Output: 7
    }

    public enum EnumClass {
        PHONE1(5),
        PHONE2(6),
        PHONE3(7);
        private final Integer digit;

        EnumClass (Integer digit) {
            this.digit = digit;
        }

        public Integer getDigit() {
            return digit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 3):

`Enum` в `java` - это синтаксический сахар. На самом деле, это обычные классы:

Приведу пример, есть следующий енум:

```
enum ColorEnum {
    RED, GREEN, YELLOW
}
```

Если мы его скопилируем и посмотрим байткод то обнаружим несколько интересных вещей:

- это будет обычный класс наследуемый от `java.lang.Enum`

  ```
  final class ru.izebit.ColorEnum extends java.lang.Enum<ColorEnum>
  ```
- Переменные енума это всего лишь public static final поля - объекты данного класса

  ```
  public static final ru.izebit.ColorEnum RED;
  public static final ru.izebit.ColorEnum GREEN;
  public static final ru.izebit.ColorEnum YELLOW;
  ```
- у данного класса появится несколько методов:

  ```
  public static ru.izebit.ColorEnum[] values();
  public static ru.izebit.ColorEnum valueOf(java.lang.String);
  ```
- появится статический блок, где происходит создание объектов, инициализация и заполнение массива `ColourEnum`, который возвращается в методе `values`

Поэтому те методы которые вы обнаружили либо определены в классе `java.lang.Enum` либо их сгенерировал компилятор

Comment: Ответ правильный, я проголосовал за него. Хорошо бы ещё добавить команду просмотра байткода: `javap -p ColorEnum`

Answer (score 2):

Вы говорите об статической версии метода `valueOf`, принимающий два параметра, но используете вариант метода экземпляра, принимающий один параметр.

Пример использования статической версии:

```
EnumClass version = Enum.valueOf(EnumClass.class, "PHONE3");
System.out.println(version.name());
```

Первый параметр - это объект `Class <?>`, а второй это искомая константа перечисления